# Warning: mysqli_fetch_object() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, string given in E:\xampp\htdocs\getSubCatList.php on line 9

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Please help me to find the bug in my code.

It shows following **Warning** :

> mysqli_fetch_object() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, string given in E:\xampp\htdocs\getSubCatList.php on line 9

**Code:**

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","dbname");
$parentname = $_POST['$parentname'];
$con->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
$sql1 ="SELECT `fld_category_id` FROM `tbl_category_master` WHERE `fld_category_name` = '$parentname' limit 1";
//$result = mysql_query($sql1);
try{
$value = mysqli_fetch_object($sql1);
$cat_id= $value;}
catch (Exception $e) { 

echo $e->errorMessage(); }

$sql="SELECT `fld_category_name` FROM `tbl_category_master` WHERE `fld_parent_category_id` = '$cat_id'";
 $result1=$con->query($sql);
        while($e=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1)){
    $output[]=$e; **strong text**
    }   

    $con->close();
?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mysql\_fetch\_array()/mysql\_fetch\_assoc()/mysql\_fetch\_row() expects parameter 1 to be resource or mysqli\_result, boolean given](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973202/mysql-fetch-array-mysql-fetch-assoc-mysql-fetch-row-expects-parameter-1-to)

Comment: Add  `$result=$con->query($sql1);` after this query `$sql1 ="SELECT `fld_category_id` FROM `tbl_category_master` WHERE `fld_category_name` = '$parentname' limit 1";` on line 9

Comment: @Priyanka S, please check my answer. I hope it solves your issue

Comment: No, now   I am getting "Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string " this error

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Forget to execute query

```
 $sql1 ="SELECT `fld_category_id` FROM `tbl_category_master` WHERE `fld_category_name` = '$parentname' limit 1";
```

execute your query

```
$result=$con->query($sql1);

try{
    // fetch data from query result
    $value = mysqli_fetch_object($result);
    $cat_id= $value->fld_category_id;
    // rest of your code

} catch (Exception $ex) {

}
```

Comment: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

Comment: add `$cat_id= $value->fld_category_id;` after `$value = mysqli_fetch_object($result);`

Comment: Have you check above??

Answer (score 0):

I think you have missed one line before `$value = mysqli_fetch_object($sql1);`

It is about executing your query.

```
$data = mysqli_query($con,$sql1);
```

And Then your code

```
$value = mysqli_fetch_object($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

you did not excute the query $sql1 yet 
put this line **-which you already did in the second query-** after the query

```
$result1=$con->query($sql1);
```

Answer (score -1):

Add this in your code :

```
$result=$con->query($sql1);
```

To something like this :

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","dbname");
$parentname = $_POST['$parentname'];
$con->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
$sql1 ="SELECT `fld_category_id` FROM `tbl_category_master` WHERE `fld_category_name` = '$parentname' limit 1";

$result=$con->query($sql1); // add this in your code to execute query

try{
$value = mysqli_fetch_object($result);
//$cat_id= $value; // try changing this line to this
$cat_id= $value->fld_category_id;
}
catch (Exception $e) { 

echo $e->errorMessage(); }

$sql="SELECT `fld_category_name` FROM `tbl_category_master` WHERE `fld_parent_category_id` = '$cat_id'";
 $result1=$con->query($sql);
        while($e=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1)){
    $output[]=$e; 
    }   

    $con->close();
?>
```

Comment: Now  i am getting new error : Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

Comment: have you changed this line as well `
$value = mysqli_fetch_object($result);` , @PriyankaS

Comment: also add `$cat_id= $value->fld_category_id;`

Comment: @PriyankaS, I guess I was the first one to tell you know issue by mentioning it in comments. But still you have marked other answer as acceptable. Its not good, for this kind of situation users would never answer to your questions